# Ammy admin - remote desktop is unavailable error after connect

Tags: remote-control

I'm using Ammyy Admin. I've set all permisions. However once connected I receive "Remote desktop is unavailable" message. Why and how to fix this?

**upd** if I have windows rdp connected then I'm able to use ammyy admin rdp. But once i disconnect windows rdp, ammyy admin rdp is also disconnected. This is strange and makes ammyy admin useless (in my configuration). I need ammyy admin rdp to work even if windows rdp is not connected.

Answer (score 0):

- This happens when remote server program is closed ammyy that is.
- Check firewall settings on 3d party antivirus or firewall's
- If you are running windows(Vista,7,8) then try running as administrators right

Comment: how should I tune firewall to let ammyy works? what ports should be opened etc. ?

Comment: What kind of os are u running | Are u using any current antivirus if so which one => write about both system's remote, and the client side

Comment: windows server 2008 r2 on server side and windows 8 pro + windows defender on client side. After all I've used another solution so this question is probably not important anymore..